# Calling multiple methods one after the others using a single button in Canvas to animate psudocodes

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to animate pseudo-codes to show students how an algorithm works. I use canvas to present pseudo-code and then a button (Next) that with each click should highlight the current line of the pseudo-code being executed. According to my search, I use addEventListner() method to respond to "click" event but it seems that the button does not respond to the "click" event. Currently, the button is outside the canvas and it seems that it should be this way.

Any help is greatly appreciated. 
My HTML code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>To animate a psudocode calling multiple methods one at a time using a single button.</p>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px;">
<canvas id="c001" width="500" height="510" style="border:4px solid #000000;">
Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>

<button id="myBtn">Next</button>

<script>

// Declare CONSTANTS. Left and Top positions
const LEFT = 55
const TOP = 50

//########## Set the font size and weight ##########
const FONT = "18px _sans";     // Set the font size 18 and font type sans 
family

//########## Set the color of the text ##########
const COLOR = "#000000"; 

// Declare Psudocode statements
const LINE01 = "statement01"
const LINE02 = "statement02"
const LINE03 = "statement03"
const LINE04 = "statement04"
const LINE05 = "statement05"
const LINE06 = "statement06"
const LINE07 = "statement07"
const LINE08 = "statement08"
const LINE09 = "statement09"
const LINE10 = "statement10"
const LINE11 = "statement11"
const LINE12 = "statement12"
const LINE13 = "statement13"
const LINE14 = "statement14"
const LINE15 = "statement15"
const LINE16 = "statement16"

var c = document.getElementById("c001");
var rec = c.getContext("2d");
rec.rect(0,0,50,510)
rec.stroke()

// Input Rectangle
var recinput = c.getContext("2d");
recinput.rect(300,0,200,250)
recinput.stroke()
var input = c.getContext("2d");
input.font = FONT;
input.fillStyle = COLOR;
input.fillText("Input", 375, 30);

// Output Rectangle
var recoutput = c.getContext("2d");
recinput.rect(300,250,200,260)
recinput.stroke()
var output = c.getContext("2d");
output.font = FONT;
output.fillStyle = COLOR;
output.fillText("Output", 375, 275);

// Arrow: This arrow appears next to the current statement being executed. 
var arrow=c.getContext("2d");
arrow.lineWidth = 3;
arrow.strokeStyle = '#008000';

// Display psudocode - ONLY 2 Lines for now
fn1(false);    // Display 1st line of psudocode
fn2(false);    // Display 1st line of psudocode

// By pressing the button labeled Next, each function invoked to place an 
arrow to indicate the current statement being executed. 
x = document.getElementById("myBtn");

x.addEventListener("click", fn1(true)); // It seems that the button does not 
working correctly and does not respond to "click" event.
x.addEventListener("click", fn2(true)); // It seems that the button does not 
working correctly and does not respond to "click" event.

function fn1(f01){
// Line 01 - Display 1st line of psudocode
var r01 = c.getContext('2d');
rec.clearRect(0,0,50,500);
if (f01 == true) {    // true: arrow appears to indicate this line being 
    executed 
    arrow.beginPath();
    arrow.moveTo(35,35);
    arrow.lineTo(45,45);
    arrow.lineTo(20,45);
    arrow.moveTo(45,45);
    arrow.lineTo(35,55);
    arrow.stroke();}
else {
    r01.font = FONT;
    r01.fillStyle = COLOR;
    r01.fillText(LINE01,LEFT,TOP);}
}

function fn2(f02) { 
// Line 02   
var r02 = c.getContext('2d');
rec.clearRect(0,0,50,500);
if (f02 == true) {      // true: arrow appears to indicate this line being 
executed 
    arrow.beginPath();
    arrow.moveTo(35,65);
    arrow.lineTo(45,75);
    arrow.lineTo(20,75);
    arrow.moveTo(45,75);
    arrow.lineTo(35,85);
    arrow.stroke();}
else {
   r02.font = FONT;
   r02.fillStyle = COLOR;
   r02.fillText(LINE02,LEFT,TOP+30); } 
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning the function to the click event, but the return value of the `fn1(true)` and `fn2(true)` function *calls* that you are making in the addEventListener.

If you put a `console.log('I am here')` in your functions and reload the page, you'll see those logs being written.

Since those functions return nothing (meaning `undefined`) the EventListener won't know what to do with it.

Solve it by using:

```
x.addEventListener("click", fn1);
```

Or if you need the `true` or any other parameter:

```
x.addEventListener("click", function() { fn1(true); });
```